# how to enable a floating action button through a function call?

Tags: java, android, sip, floating-action-button

I am implementing a simple sip call using android sipmanager. Es soon as call is established between two agent, i want to display below listed floating action button on the screen. but some how it never activate below list of code to make that button visible on successful call. it does shows log. Any help would be highly appreciated

```
SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {


            /**
             * Name: onCallEstablished
             * Description: onCallEstablished is called when the
             * user establishes a call. This method
             * will enable the User to talk to the
             * person on the opposite line.
             */


           @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {



               super.onCallEstablished(call);

               call.startAudio();
               call.setSpeakerMode(true);
               //it does shows log in console 
               Log.e("$$", "Manager was instantiated");  

              // it doesnt change floating action button to visible
               View view7 =findViewById(R.id.fab6);
               view7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

               setText("Call ESTABLISEHED");

                if (call.isMuted()) {
                    call.toggleMute();
                }



           }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `fab.show()/fab.hide()` instead of `setVisibility()`

Comment: can you give an example how to implement show ,hide with reference to my code above

Comment: @tashidelek, why you change accepted answer. I gave you the solution first

Comment: fab.show doesnt works . any help would be highly appreciated . i havent accepted answer yet

Answer (score 2):

You should assign it to a `FloatingActionButton` object, not `View`. Then use `show()` and `hide()` methods.

Comment: higly appreciate for an example with reference to my code

Comment: FloatingActionButton fab7 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab7);
   fab7.hide();